# How do we find the value of a?

Tags: functions

The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)
= 3x + 1$ for $x ≤ a$, where $a$ is a constant. The function $g$ is defined
by $g(x)
= −1 − x^2$  for $x ≤ −1$.
(i) Find the largest value of $a$ for which the composite function $g\circ f$ can be formed.

Answer (score 2):

The range of $f$ would be $(-\infty, 3a+1]$, we need the range to be a subset of the domain of $g$.

$$(-\infty, 3a+1] \subseteq (-\infty, -1]$$

To make $a$ to be as large as possible,

Set $$3a+1=-1$$ and solve for $a$.

Comment: Why the range of f is to be a subset of the domain of g?

Comment: Let's consider what happens if we allow $a=0$ for example. In that case, $f(0)=1$, Now we evaluate $g(f(0))=g(1)$, we realized that $g(1)$ is not well defined. $g$ only take inputs which are at most $-1$.

Comment: Is there a site I can learn to solve the domain and range of composition functions?

Comment: Also, there's a second part to it. 

For the case where a=-1.
Solve the equation fgx+14=0. 

Here we got +2 and -2. But we only selected -2. Why so?

Comment: when we define a function, we tell the whole world what values does a function take in via the domain. In this case, $g$ takes in values that are less than or equal to $-1$.